# Why was this answer regarding an iOS 8 file upload bug deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25936215/1331430) being linked around in all the social networks, and now it has been deleted by a diamond moderator. Why?

As far as I can see, it looks like a valid answer.

For <10k:

[image: deleted answer]

Comment: Sounds like the post was flagged as Not An Answer and the moderator deleted without checking properly.

Comment: @AstroCB: no, it is not. The link is there as evidence, not in leu of an answer. If you read the linked blog post you'll see that the answer could stand on its own without the link too.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What happened was that a user posted the exact same copied and pasted answer across a bunch of different questions. This was flagged by the system, and a moderator removed all but one of them as a result, telling them to leave distinct answers to each question, or to vote to close as a duplicate.

The questions all look to be related to the same core issue, so I've closed them as duplicates of a canonical question that has this particular answer on it, and restored that version of this answer.